# PHP: static attribute does not accept assignment

Tags: php, static, variable-assignment

I'm starting to get frustrated with an issue I'm having. I'm assigning a value to a static attribute called error, using an if statement. the funny thing is that only the second if actually assigns a value, while the first if doesn't

```
if (mb_strlen($password) > 10 || mb_strlen($email) > 35)
{
    // 1st Error:
    self::$error = "PASS_EMAIL_TOO_LONG";
    die(self::$error);
    return false;
}
if (mb_strlen($password) < 8) 
{
    self::$error = "PASS_TOO_SHORT";
    die(self::$error);
    return false;
}
```

Why "PASS_EMAIL_TOO_LONG" never gets assigned to $error ?

I'm using die to see the value, but it always dies when entering the first if block, and returns an empty value, On the other hand the second "if" is working as intended.

Comment: Have you declared the variable static in your class? Could you please post some class code

Comment: Of course I did, if I wouldn't have, then the second if would fail as well.

Comment: you don't need to check that length > 35. If this is the case, it will be > 10

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not quite following you. Password should not exceed 10 and email should not exceed 35. What did you mean by that?

Comment: The code you pasted works fine, I checked. Search for some other mistakes or paste some more code.

Comment: My bad, That's what happens when you refine a method from the bottom. I didn't notice if (!self::validate_email($email)) { return false; } returns false before everything else.